# updating labels when switching dataset (+removing older one)

Tags: d3.js, label, updating

I've been drawing a planetarium with planets and labels on it :

```
svg.append("circle").attr("r", 20).attr("cx", w/2)
    .attr("cy", h/2).attr("class", "sun");
svg.append("text").attr("x", w/2)
    .attr("y", h/2).attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("fill", "grey").text("VICTOR HUGO");

  var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")

  var orbit = container.selectAll(".orbit")
                        .data(dataset, key)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("class", "orbit")
                        .attr("r", 0);
                        //function(d) {return (d.key * ((w/2)/151) + 20); });

  var planets = container.selectAll(".planet")
                       .data(dataset, key)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                       .attr("class", "planet")
                       .attr("r", function(d) {return 5;})
                       .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
                       .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y; })
                       .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                            stopTooltip = false                 
                            showTooltip(d);
                        });

d3.select("svg").on("click", function(d) {stopTooltip = true;});
  var texts = container.selectAll(".text")
                       .data(dataset, key)
                       .enter()
                       .append("text")
                       .attr("class", "text")
                       .attr("dx", function(d) {return d.x;})
                       .attr("dy", ".35em")
                       .text(function(d) {return d.titre});
```

Then, I've been adding a legend and a click function, so that when you click on one or another of the legend subtitle, the dataset is updated (if you look at the tooltips, it is indeed updated).

```
////////////////////////Legend//////////////////////////////////


update = function(newDataset, key){

 var newplanets = container.selectAll(".planet").data(newDataset, key);
     newplanets.enter().append("circle");
     newplanets.transition()
     .duration(0)
     .attr("r", function(d) {return 5;})
             .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
             .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y; })
             .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                      stopTooltip = false                   
                            showTooltip(d);
                        });
        newplanets.exit().remove();




  var newtexts = container.selectAll(".text").data(newDataset, key);
      newtexts.enter().append("text");
      newtexts.transition()
          .duration(0)
          .attr("class", "text")
                .attr("dx", function(d) {return d.x;})
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) {return d.titre});
      newtexts.exit().remove();        
}


    var legendRectSize = 7;                                  
    var legendSpacing = 20;                                    

    var VictorHugoClass = [
          { "VHClassName": '...Auteur (oeuvre)', "VHClass": r990o, "color": "#0000FF" },
          { "VHClassName": '...Auteur (expression)', "VHClass": r990e, "color": "#FBA10D" },
        ];  

    //Initiate container around Legend
    var legendContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class","legendContainer")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + "," + (h - 90) + ")");
    //Create title of Legend
    var legendTitle = legendContainer.append('text')                                     
          .attr('x', 0)              
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)  
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .attr('class', 'legendTitle')
          .attr('transform', function() {                     
            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          
            var offset =  height * VictorHugoClass.length / 2;     
            var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;                       
            var vert = -2.3 * height - offset;                       
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        
          })
          .attr("fill", "black")
          .text("Victor Hugo en tant que...")
          .call(wrap, 200);

    //Create container per circle/text pair  
    var legend = legendContainer
          .selectAll('.legend')     
          .data(VictorHugoClass)                              
          .enter()                                                
          .append('g')   
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     
            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          
            var offset =  height * VictorHugoClass.length / 2;     
            var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;                       
            var vert = i * height - offset;                       
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        
          })
          .on("click", function(d) {

              update(d.VHClass, d.key);

          });                                           
        //Append circles to Legend
        legend.append('circle')                                     
          .attr('r', legendRectSize)  
          .attr('cx', 4)              
          .attr('cy', legendRectSize/2 - legendSpacing)
          .attr("opacity", 1)
          .style("fill", "white")
          .style('stroke', function(d) {return d.color;});                                  
        //Append text to Legend
        legend.append('text')                                     
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing/2)              
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
          .attr("fill", "black")
          .text(function(d) { return d.VHClassName; });
```

Nevertheless, the labels won't update with the planets, and some of the data of the former dataset are still remaining when the second dataset is loaded into the visualization. My Plunker is here for more details : http://plnkr.co/edit/UnhqCZhME7ymxdIbpcIj?p=preview

Thank you very much for your help in this...

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on, but there's two obvious mistakes -- first, you're calling `.on()` on a transition, which you can't do in D3. Call `.on()` on the selection instead and then add the transition. Second, you're selecting the nodes based on the planet class, but you're not assigning that class to the elements you add. I've fixed those things [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/98kMQK5mDvi3cR2dNMAx?p=preview).

Comment: It's working well, thank you very much. There's still a bug when clicking several time on the legend though, but I'll try to fix that as soon as possible.

Comment: If you can describe what exactly the bug is or ideally provide a smaller example that makes it obvious what's going wrong that would help.

Comment: I've made a new updated example that I hope simpler here : http://plnkr.co/edit/dJLmQGDDPc2zueRh08U4?p=preview. If you try to play on the legend as with a power switch, clicking several time on "author of songs" and "author of prefaces", you'll see that the labels are not matching with the planets anymore. Thank you again for your help here.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a fundamental problem to me -- you're updating the data bound to the elements to create the circular motion. That is, the state of the animation is encoded in the data. When you're changing the data (which is what happens when you click the legend), this state is lost. I would restructure so that the data remains the same and you're only changing the name of the attribute that determines text and colour. That is, the bound data doesn't change, but what's extracted from it.

Comment: That was exactly that ! Here, I've just removed the x attribute on the text in the update function : http://plnkr.co/edit/dJLmQGDDPc2zueRh08U4?p=preview. Thank you very much !

Comment: Ah ok, that wasn't actually what I meant -- when you click the legend, the nodes jump because the data is different.